# Google Chrome PDF Viewer checkboxes are not working

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

We are having issues in the Chrome PDF viewer with generated PDFs whereby the check-boxes are not changing state (i.e. getting checked) and some fields lose values when you TAB out of them but when they gain focus the value shows again.

Has anyone else experienced this? And if so, any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

I updated my Chrome to the latest version and the PDF works correctly in Adobe Acrobat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the generated PDFs don't have appearances for the check boxes. Without appearances, the viewer doesn't know what to show when the field state changes. How you add the appearances will depend on the library you're using to create the PDF.

It works correctly in Acrobat because Acrobat will create appearances when they are missing. Chrome doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @joelgeraci. It's peculiar though because we haven't changed anything on the PDFs and while the checkbox is there, checking it doesn't... well.. check it. :)

I'll look into the appearances . I am using ABCPdf and EvoPDF to generate the PDFs.

Comment: I'm guessing, I haven't tried it, that Chrome is noticing the user interaction and changing the internal "exported" value of the checkbox, but can't, as @joelgeraci says, display the result.

Answer (score 0):

I added a fill color to the check box and that solved the problem.

Adjust the check box style by:

1. Open your form in Adobe Acrobat
2. Edit the PDF form (My option is Prepare Form)
3. Double-click the Check Box to open the Check Box Properties dialog box
4. Click the Appearance tab
5. Change the Fill Color to white (or any color)
6. Click close on the Check Box Properties dialog box
7. Save your PDF
8. Open your PDF in Chrome and check your work.