# Print preview, checkboxes not visible

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, microsoft-edge

I´ve got an problem.

I want to print a pdf with checked checkboxes. When i open the print-preview via chrome or edge the checkboxes are not visible..

Need heeeeelp

Comment: I think your short description is similar to [this question](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/pdf-form-doesn-t-print-checkboxes/m-p/9835171) and you can refer to its answer. Can you provide more details if I misunderstood anything?

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar question asked at: [Google Chrome PDF Viewer checkboxes are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097866/google-chrome-pdf-viewer-checkboxes-are-not-working)

The upvoted response:

> It's likely that the generated PDFs don't have appearances for the check boxes. Without appearances, the viewer doesn't know what to show when the field state changes. How you add the appearances will depend on the library you're using to create the PDF.
>
> It works correctly in Acrobat because Acrobat will create appearances when they are missing. Chrome doesn't.

It's hard to say what your issue is without more detail. If the checkboxes are working in the pdf view, but not showing up as "checked" in print preview then it may be an issue with the PDF itself.

One workaround could be to use [Adobe Acrobat Reader](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/pdf-reader.html) as it's free and I find its annotation functions pretty full featured, but this doesn't meet your original criteria/question in regards to Chrome or Edge.

Comment: The problem is that all checkboxes(checked an unchecked) are not available in print preview..